# Creating DB with Visual Studio 2008

Tags: .net, database

I want to create a database application with Visual Studio. I wonder what type of DB to choose? I was thinking about Access db. But I dont have Office installed. I have MS SQL server 2008 installed but I doubt I need to use it for a very simple database with small number of rows

I need to create a very simple database app for personal use. Can anyone recommend basic steps

Let me put it another way - can I create a GUI app that would use a datafile only - so that running DB server was not required much like Access files so that I can use on any computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whenever i want to do this i just create a typed DataSet; just add a DataSet item to your project, and then you can create tables/columns/keys/constraints directly within the DataSet editor. the IDE will generate code classes to make it easy to work with the DataSet tables and columns statically by name, and the DB you create is saved as an xml schema.

then, when you create an instance of the DataSet, you can read/write the data from/to disk with the Xml output functions. (i believe WriteXml and ReadXml...) i have also played around a little with writing my own function to write out the data in a more compact format to save space.

DataSets do have some performance issues if you have lots of information; but one of the nice things about using them is that you can always migrate to a database using the structure and then use TableAdapters to read from/write to the database. if you have really a lot of data this might be the way to go; but when i've been prototyping or just didn't have serious amounts of data, then in those cases i've had good success with just an XML-based DataSet.

DataSets are easy to work with as well, they support relational functionality very well, and they also allow you to operate in a mode where you can accept or reject changes.  i know some people really don't like them but I'm quite fond myself. :)

Answer (score 3):

How about [Sql Server Compact Edition?](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx)